# passing variable into componentdidmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update my fetch API call in the componentdidmount to match the input in react but I am havin a tough time passing my input into the templete literal of the URl. Can anyone shed some light on this please?

code-

```
search(x) {
        console.log(this.state);
        console.log(x);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let food = 'cheese';
        const url = `https://edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com/parser?ingr=${food}`;
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'x-rapidapi-host': 'edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com',
                'x-rapidapi-key': 'removed for privacy'
            }
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => console.log(data.hints));
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on codesandbox.

Comment: If you use .then and .catch syntax you don't need to mark a function as async. Async should be used only when you use await syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to do something like this. The key thing is that `componentDidUpdate` responds to any change in state, so if you're updating state with a new value from an input, it will run.

```
class Thing extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set up the state with food and data properties
    this.state = { food: '', data: [] };
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
  }

  // Have a separate method for your API call that can
  // grab the food from state and build then endpoint
  doApiCall () {
    const { food } = this.state;
    return fetch(`https://something.com/${food}`);
  }

  // componentDidUpdate is called after
  // a state change call. It calls the api method and then
  // updates the state with the data
  async componentDidUpdate() {
    const response = await this.doApiCall();
    const data = await reponse.json();
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  // When the input is changed, update the state
  // (which causes componentDidUpdate to run)
  handleSearch(e) {
    const { target: { value } } = e;
    this.setState({ food: value });
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="string" onChange={this.handleSearch} />
      </div>
     );

  }

}
```

Comment: thanks man, this led me down what i think is a correct path. So i took your advice on the how updating the state can make componentDidUpdate() render again and created an object called food in my state. Now i wanna update the state of this food object everytime i type i click search and feed an input in. Right now my code is as below, could you show me how to change the state of food with x? :) code is here- https://www.codepile.net/pile/DZry8nzl

Comment: I fixed it! All i had to do was create a new object called food, like @Andy suggested and then update the state with it. When the state was updated, I called componentDidUpdate which had an api call with a template literal that contained the value in the food from state. I love this helpful community! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Kisho, I just reviewed my answer and made a small change. If you set `food` as empty in the state initially, you can remove `componentDidMount` and just use `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Thats what i did mate :) @Andy